# Merge Rules in Hotchocolate GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using hotchocolate in .net core 3 and I'm trying to stitch / merge two objects of the same type into one object.

https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v10/stitching#merge-rules
The documentation here talks about merge rules. "In most cases the default merge rules should be enough. But with more domain knowledge about the source schemas one could write more aggressive merge rules."

Where can I find more info about merge rules? How to write one of my own?
I'm trying to merge two objects of the same type into one. For example

```
Object A of type something
Prop 1
Prop 2

Object B of type something
Prop 3
Prop 4
```

Should be stitched / merged into

```
An object of type something with
Prop 1
Prop 2
Prop 3
Prop 4
```

How can I achieve this?
Edit: I want to accomplish the same as written here: https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/stitch-type-merging/

Comment: The new stitching docs are currently not yet merged to the live website, but you can find the open PR for those here: https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/pull/2780